# How to purge zookeeper logs with PurgeTxnLog?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Zookeeper's rapidly pooping its internal binary files all over our production environment.
According to:    http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html
and
http://dougchang333.blogspot.com/2013/02/zookeeper-cleaning-logs-snapshots.html
this is expected behavior and you must call org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog
regularly to rotate its poop.

So:

```
% ls -l1rt /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/
total 314432
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67108880 Jun 26 18:00 log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   947092 Jun 26 18:00 snapshot.e99b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67108880 Jun 27 05:00 log.e99d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1620918 Jun 27 05:00 snapshot.1e266
... many more

% sudo java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6.jar::lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:conf \
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog \
    /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 -n 3
```

but I get:

```
% ls -l1rt /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/
... all the existing logs plus a new directory
/tmp/zookeeper/version-2/version-2
```

Am I doing something wrong?

zookeeper-3.4.6/

Comment: I'd like to +2 this since it made me laugh today!  Thanks for that.

Comment: Your data dir probably is /tmp/zookeeper not /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 (version-2 is a zk internal thing)... I guess, it is not working for me either

Comment: Maybe -- all I know is that folder filled up the filesystem, which is unreasonable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ZooKeeper now has an Autopurge feature as of 3.4.0. Take a look at https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html

It says you can use `autopurge.snapRetainCount` and `autopurge.purgeInterval`

**autopurge.snapRetainCount**

> New in 3.4.0: When enabled, ZooKeeper auto purge feature retains the autopurge.snapRetainCount most recent snapshots and the corresponding transaction logs in the dataDir and dataLogDir respectively and deletes the rest. Defaults to 3. Minimum value is 3.

**autopurge.purgeInterval**

> New in 3.4.0: The time interval in hours for which the purge task has to be triggered. Set to a positive integer (1 and above) to enable the auto purging. Defaults to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Since I'm not hearing a fix via Zookeeper, this was an easy workaround:

```
COUNT=6
DATADIR=/tmp/zookeeper/version-2/
ls -1drt ${DATADIR}/* | head --lines=-${COUNT} | xargs sudo rm -f
```

Should run once a day from a cron job or jenkins to prevent zookeeper from exploding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the parameter `dataDir` and `snapDir` with the value that is configured as `dataDir` in your .properties file of zookeeper.

If your configuration looks like the following.

```
dataDir=/data/zookeeper
```

You need to call `PurgeTxnLog` (version 3.5.9) like the following if you want to keep the last 10 logs/snapshots

```
java -cp zookeeper.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:conf org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog /data/zookeeper /data/zookeeper -n 10
```